# What does row_produced count represent in snowflake query_history view when query is MERGE from file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am executing MERGE query to perform CDC operation.  I have a target table which is holding around 50 million records and the incoming file which is source for MERGE contains 230 records. There is simple join in ID of table and id column from file data. After execution , the History view shows records inserted 200 and records updated 30.  However its showing rows_produced as 5K.  I need to understand what does rows_produced in this case. Does it show the rows return as a part of join ?  if its yes, then it should be matching the row count of file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that rows_produced is the total number of records that were created when the underlying micropartitions were written out.

For example, if you updated 1 record, you are actually recreating the entire micropartition of data that this 1 record exists in (micropartitions are immutable, so therefore never updated).  If that 1 record exists in a micropartition that contains 100 records, then you'd get an output that has 1 record updated, but 100 `rows_produced`.

This information is "interesting" but not helpful when trying to make sure the right outcome of your `MERGE` statement.  Using the insert, update, and delete output for the `MERGE` is the accurate way to look at that.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  This helps to clarify the confusion around rows_produced column.   Is it possible to display rows_inserted, rows_updated and rows_deleted in History View so when we review query, it can be quickly visible rather than finding the same information from query_history or table function